# File Not Found When Access Direct File on Wordpress Using Nginx and PHP-FPM

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm running Wordpress on Nginx 1.12.2 and PHP-fpm using this configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myweb.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.myweb.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    root /var/www/myweb/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name www.myweb.com;

    listen 80;
    location / {
        #mod-rewrite to enable friendly url (wp permalink)
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac). Keep logging the 
    # requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

It works fine, but there's an error when executing .php file directly.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmwhx.jpg)

The ON|OFF switch directly accesses file:
`http://www.myweb.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/setStatus.php`

and return 404 file not found. The same errors I got when my cron try to access .php file under plugin directory.

How to set up correctly?
I need your guide.

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, all works but the direct link to any php files. I suggest switching your php location block to something similar to the following:

```
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_hide_header "X-Powered-By";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Don't forget to reload nginx before testing.

More on [HTTP_PROXY](https://httpoxy.org) parameter and why it is used